# WPF w/ Unity Loading Modules Based on Interface

Tags: wpf, unity-container, prism

I'm writing a WPF app using Prism/Unity.

I have my main app (with a bootstrapper).

I have interfaces for each of my modules. For example:

**MyModuleA** implements **IMyModuleA**

**MyModuleB** implements **IMyModuleB**

I want to implement loose coupling and dependency injection.

So in my bootstrapper, I want to specify that I'm loading a library (type) based on an interface.  This would allow me build the module independently.

In my bootstrapper, I have the following:

```
protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog() {
    base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();

    string path = @"Modules.MyModuleA.dll";
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
    var type = assembly.GetType("Modules.MyModuleA.MyModuleA");
    ModuleCatalog.AddModule(new ModuleInfo {
        ModuleName = type.Name,
        ModuleType = type.AssemblyQualifiedName,
        Ref = new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute).ToString()
    });
}
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I must say this is not the best way to do that because you are still specifying type by string which is even worse because leaves space for human error. Dependency injection and loose coupling is about using Interface and registering different types implementing that interface on the fly.

If you want to load different modules on the fly for the same interface you should use your own Bootstraper which is called at desired code path. And inside of it use:

```
if(shouldUseEmail)                
 Container.RegisterType<IFeedbackService, EmailFeedbackService>();
else
 Container.RegisterType<IFeedbackService, SMSFeedbackService>();
```

And later on you resolve like this:

```
var feedbackService = Container.Resolve<IFeddbackService>();
```

Or use DI (dependency injection in constructors)

Comment: Vidas, I agree with you and that's what I'm trying to do.  However, in your example, I'm still having to include a reference at design time to _EmailFeebackService_ (or, in my case, _MyModuleA_)

In my ConfigureModuleCatalog, how do I write:
    Container.RegisterType<IMyModuleA, MyModuleA>();

with still only adding a reference to _IMyModuleA_?

Comment: Also, this isn't necessarily a service, but a module, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I thought the whole point of DI was to **not** have to provide a concrete class, just the interface?  Then I simple add the DLL of the concrete class to the project at runtime.  Since's it's implementing an interface, I should just be able to call (as in your example) feedbackService.MyMethod() and it would simply call the concrete class's method.

With the approach above, I'm still having to add a reference to the concrete EmailFeedbackService, which means (and correct me if I'm wrong), when I recompile EmailFeedbackService, I'll need to recompile the app...